# Node Sync Issue

Tags: stellar-core

I am running a private stellar network and try to sync three nodes. From Node I am getting below message.

[Overlay DEBUG] Peer 127.0.0.1:11625 is not preferred

From Node3 getting below message
[Overlay DEBUG] Peer 127.0.0.1:11625 is not preferred
[Overlay DEBUG] Peer 127.0.0.1:11627 is not preferred.

**I tried to solve these issue by putting below attribute one by one testing phase.
In phase1, I have used CATCHUP_COMPLETE=false.
In phase2, CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true,phase3 I have used CATCHUP_RECENT=1024 .
But did not able to sync. Is there something I missed out.**

Answer (score 0):

At least you could most likely fix that debug message by adding all your nodes to the other nodes configs:

`PREFERRED_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11625", "127.0.0.1:11626", "127.0.0.1:11625"]`

and/or

`PREFERRED_PEER_KEYS=["GA...Node1PubKey", "GA...Node2PubKey", "GA...Node3PubKey"]`

CATCHUP_RECENT=1 should work if there are no connection issues. For CATCHUP_COMPLETE all your nodes need to be able to access (ideally all your other nodes) archvies => check your archive configs. Completely resetting your malfunctioning node (or better spawning a fourth node to prevent accidentally data loss) might be an option. Post your config if you still have issues.

Comment: In my case all there nodes are showing "Peer not preferred" , so is there any way to identify the malfunctioning node and config file archive.